# Emacs daemon/server with slash in the name

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

When I try the following command it works as expected:

`emacsclient -t -s foo`

Tries to connect to an emacs daemon named `foo' and if no such daemon is found starts one and then connects to it.

but this does not:

`emacsclient -t -s foo/bar`

It never finds the emacs daemon named `foo/bar` and is never able to connect to it.

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
Starting Emacs daemon.
```

It does, however, spawn an emacs daemon with the name "foo/bar" and I can see it with the `ps -ef | grep emacs` command

`user1   184936      1  0 Jul31 ?        00:00:00  emacs --daemon=foo/bar`

I believe this is because on linux you are not allowed to create filenames with '/' in it. The emacs --daemon=foo ends up creating a file under `/tmp/emacs709/foo` in my system. If that's the case should this not result in an appropriate error message instead of spawning a daemon and not being able to connect to it?